# PHP: Access data from a two dimensional associative array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, get

I have a page which shows a list of items from a two dimensional array like this:

```
<?php 
    for ($row = 0; $row < $arrlength; $row++)
    {
       echo "<li>";
       echo "<a href='#item-info' >";              
       echo $items[$row]["Item"];
       echo "</a>"; 
       echo "</li>";
    }
?>
```

I want to be able to have the user click the link of the item they want which will the take them to a page which shows all of that items information.
My array looks something like this:

```
$items = array( array(Item =>"Jeans",
                      Colour =>"Blue",
                      In stock =>"Yes"),
```

I've been looking at php tutorials online and I believe that I'm suppose to use GET methods in my url where the `#item-info` is but I'm not too sure what the best way to do this is.

The reason I want this is because my array contains nearly 1000 items and it would be a long process to make 1000 item-info pages so I just want to make one page which just displays all of the specific items information on one separate page.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: You need to build your link based on the current value of `$items[$row]`. Can you add what your url should look like and the complete value of `$items[$row]`?

Comment: I believe I'd want it to look something like this mysite.com/fyp/index.php#item-info?iteminfo=jeans

Answer (score 3):

You need to quote your keys:

```
$rooms = array(
    array(
        "Item" =>"Jeans",
        "Colour" =>"Blue",
        "In stock" =>"Yes"
    )
);
```

Also, I assume that the array you are accessing in the loop is actually called `$items` and the use of `$rooms` here was just an example.

My apologies, on to answer your actual question: You seem to want a bookmark tag.  You'd build this by using the following:

```
echo "<a href='" . $items[$row]["Item"] . "-" . $items[$row]["Colour"] . "'></a>";
```

Then you could use the bookmark hash in your URL matching whichever bookmark you want to link to move to.  For example, to go to the item in the above example array your bookmark hash would be: `#Jeans-Blue`

Comment: My code seems to be working so far with my item list for loop. is it really necessary?

Comment: Sorry, I answered your heading and not your actual question.  I tried to answer the main question in a follow up edit.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your current array that you have provided returns:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'stock' (T_STRING), expecting
>   ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 5

This is because you have not enclosed your keys as strings.

```
$rooms = array( array(Item =>"Jeans",
                      Colour =>"Blue",
                      In stock =>"Yes")
```

Should be:

```
$rooms = array( array("Item" =>"Jeans",
                      "Colour" =>"Blue",
                      "In stock" =>"Yes")
```

also, you have not closed off your array correctly, you have missed the closing `);`

so your ending array should be:

```
$rooms = array( array("Item" =>"Jeans",
                      "Colour" =>"Blue",
                      "In stock" =>"Yes"));
```

and how to access is as followed:

performing a `print_r($rooms);` returns:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [Item] => Jeans [Colour] => Blue [In stock] => Yes ) )
```

to access a single piece of data, you'd need to search through the key of the inner array you wish to search:

so

`echo $rooms[0]['Item'];` will print: `Jeans`

Accessing the entire array I'd personally (I know other developers will have their methods, so respect to them)

```
Foreach ($rooms AS $Primary_Array)
{
   // this searches through your primary array 
   foreach ($Primary_Array AS $Room_Keys => $Room_Value)
   {
      // This searches through your secondary level array so you can return: 
     echo '<b>'.$Room_Keys.'</b>:'.$Room_Value.'<br>'; 
     /*
      with your array provided, you will have the following output:

     **Item**: Jeans
     **Colour**: Blue
     **Instock**: Yes
     */
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm aware about the closing bracket being missed out. Obviously I didn't really want to copy the whole of my array. I know how to simply print a single piece of data. What I want to achieve is when a user clicks an item from the list, it then appends the item name to the URL and then the new page shows that specific items info

Comment: people will correct your mistakes on the example code, as that's treated as your production code.. and give me a moment to perform a few tests

Comment: @mrpopo Deadalus update on his answer seems the best approach. I would advice taking his example